# Equivalent of `set @variable = 0` in spring data jpa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to execute following queries in one go on MySQL through spring data jpa.

```
    SET @i := 0;
    UPDATE tv_episode te SET te.display_episode_no= @i:=@i+1 WHERE te.tv_season_id=season ORDER BY broadcast_date;
```

I tried finding out a solution for this on StackOverflow, but couldn't find any.

What is the equivalent of `SET @i := 0;` in spring-data-jpa? Is there a way I can execute the statement in `@Modifying` & `@Query` annotated method?

Answer (score 0):

You can run native queries by adding `nativeQuery = true` to `@Query` :

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "SET @i := 0;\n" +
      "UPDATE tv_episode te SET te.display_episode_no= @i:=@i+1 WHERE te.tv_season_id = :season", nativeQuery = true)
int updateUserSetStatusForName(@Param("season") Integer season);
```

And If you don't want to use native query you can pass parameters like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update TvEpisode te set te.displayEpisodeNo = :epiodeNo where te.tvSeasonId = :season")
int updateUserSetStatusForName(@Param("epiodeNo") Integer epiodeNo, 
  @Param("season") Integer season);
```

Comment: Your first query  won't be accepted because of the `:` symbol: `Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'`